# Tomcat+Spring boot redirect ignoring contextPath

Tags: spring, tomcat7

I'am using Spring boot and Tomcat7 to build a vehicle management system.

The base path is  localhost:8080/vehicle

My server setting:

```
server.contextPath=/vehicle
```

My IndexController:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController extends BaseController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model) {
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
}
```

But when I go straight to get this view, my path is `...../login` instead of `..../vehicle/login` And so it returns 404 Error.

Also when I tried to use `return "redirect:/vehicle/login";` it still goes to `...../login`.

So what is wrong with my code. Why the server can't recognize the contextPath.

Comment: Duplicated? with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617277/spring-boot-war-external-tomcat-context-path

Answer (score 0):

In application.properties use : `server.servlet.context-path=/contextPath`.

Example:
`server.servlet.context-path=/vehicle`

Tomcat Server:
In the webapps folder, the context path(vehicle) must be the same as the folder name(vehicle).